# Why is jQuery grabbing the parent form name when serializing a child form's values in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am attempting to loop through all forms in the page and serialize the values.  I need to get the form id or name of each form as well.

In this case, I have 2 forms inside the standard ASP.NET server form that encapsulates everything.

The problem is that when it serializes the second forms values, it writes the name of the parent ASP.NET form, not the actual form the values sit in.

The second form output works perfectly.

Here is my code and output.

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("form").each(function ()
    {
        document.write("<li>Form ID: " + $(this).attr("name"));
        document.write("<li>Form Values: " + $(this).serialize());
    });


});
```

The HTML output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/cache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="CacheTesting.aspx" id="form1" name="form1">
        <div class="aspNetHidden">

            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZJ3NbEPOwkaa9B4UXSJtqYSQBihLaZZ9uYNPO/u0XD1G" />
        </div>
        <div>
        <form name="form2" id="form2" action="#">
            <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
        </form>
        <form name="form3" id="form3" action="#">
            <select name="single">
                <option>Single</option>
                <option>Single2</option>
            </select>

            <br />

            <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
                <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
                <option>Multiple2</option>
                <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
            </select>

            <br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1" />
            <label for="ch1">check1</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2" />
            <label for="ch2">check2</label>

            <br />

            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1" />
            <label for="r1">radio1</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2" />
            <label for="r2">radio2</label>

            <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" onclick="showValues()" />

        </form>
        <p>
            <tt id="results"></tt>
        </p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is what the javascript produces:

```
Form ID: form1
Form Values: __VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZJ3NbEPOwkaa9B4UXSJtqYSQBihLaZZ9uYNPO%2Fu0XD1G&txtName=

Form ID: form3
Form Values: single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1
```

The problem is that in the first loop, the Form ID should be form2, not form1. I know this because `txtName` is a part of `form2`, not `form1`.

Anything I can do to remedy this?

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: I just noticed that if i add an empty dummy form after the initial ASP.NET generated form, everything works fine. Unfortunately this isn't the best solution because I need this jquery code to work automatically on all pages past, present and future, so adding a dummy form isn't the best idea.

Comment: Just because something seems to work, doesn't mean it will always work.  Different browsers will work differently, and deal with invalid markup in different ways.  Even if it works across all current browsers, there's no guarantee it will work in future versions.  You can't use invalid markup, or you're just asking for trouble.  Invalid markup can cause all kinds of weird problems, from styling not working correctly, to getting bumped into quirks mode, to just flat out not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use forms as containers for the pieces you want to serialize.  Put a different container around them, then serialize the inputs, selects, and textareas inside those containers.

HTML snippet:

```
        <div id='SerializationContainer'>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
        </div>
        <div id='SerializationContainer2'>
            <select name="single">
                <option>Single</option>
                <option>Single2</option>
            </select>

            <br />

            <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
                <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
                <option>Multiple2</option>
                <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
            </select>

            <br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1" />
            <label for="ch1">check1</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2" />
            <label for="ch2">check2</label>

            <br />

            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1" />
            <label for="r1">radio1</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2" />
            <label for="r2">radio2</label>

            <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" onclick="showValues()" />

        </div>
```

Script Snippet:

```
$("#SerializationContainer input,SerializationContainer select, SerializationContainer textarea").serialize();

$("#SerializationContainer2 input,SerializationContainer2 select, SerializationContainer2 textarea").serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have nested forms.  It's not valid HTML.

You can have multiple forms per page, but they cannot be nested.  ie.

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" action="#"> 
    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" /> 
</form> 

<form runat="server" method="post" action="CacheTesting.aspx" id="form1" name="form1">   
      [asp.net content goes here]
</form>
```

Comment: I realize this, but it's how ASP.NET generates HTML.  Everything is inside of a form. Including your other forms.

Comment: @Kevin - No, it doesn't.  ASP.NET only generates one form per page.  If you have more than one form, it's because you're manually adding them.  You cannot have more than one form in an HTML document, it's not valid and will cause any number of weird behaviors.

Comment: If ASP.NET generates one form per page, and you're only allowed one form in an HTML document, then you cannot use your own forms with ASP.NET?  Seems the "one form per page" quota is used up by ASP.NET

Comment: @Kevin - ASP.NET will only generate one form.  You can have multiple forms per page, you just can't have them nested.  You can move your form tags closer to the areas where you need asp.net controls to be embedded, then place your additional tags outside of the asp.net form (the one with runat="server" on it).